# How to convert column with millisecond timestamp to date in a file using bash?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to convert all values from the first column of a file that came in milliseconds timestamp to a date format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. But the output is `Di 26. Mai 15:04:00 CEST 2020000`. I am using this command:

```
cat throughput-vs-latency-40K-16.csv | sed 's/^/echo "/; s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/`date -d @\1`/; s/$/"/' | bash
```

and this is the file

```
"Time","pre_aggregate[0]-IN","pre_aggregate[10]-IN",
1590491460000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1590491475000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1590491490000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1590491505000,290.51666666666665,290.53333333333336,
1590491535000,1027.15,1027.15,1028.85,1028.8666666666666,
1590491550000,1394.1166666666666,1394.15,1394.15,1394.1333333333334,
1590491565000,1475.5333333333333,1473.3666666666666,
```

I would like to have the output bellow (please consider only the format and dismiss the correct time conversion):

```
"Time","pre_aggregate[0]-IN","pre_aggregate[10]-IN",
"2020-05-07 08:05:45",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
"2020-05-07 08:06:45",290.51666666666665,290.53333333333336,
"2020-05-07 08:07:45",1027.15,1027.15,1028.85,1028.8666666666666,
"2020-05-07 08:05:45",1394.1166666666666,1394.15,1394.15,1394.1333333333334,
"2020-05-07 08:08:45",1475.5333333333333,1473.3666666666666,
```

What am I missing in the `sed` command to have a date in this format `2020-05-07 08:09:45`?

Comment: Could you please post sample of expected output too in your post and let us know then.

Comment: sure. I added. Please consider only the time format, not the correct time conversion regarding the original time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","
}
NR > 1 {
   n = $1/1000
   cmd = "date -d @" n " +\"%Y-%m-%d %T\""
   $1 = "\"" ( (cmd | getline out) > 0 ? out : $1 ) "\""
   close(cmd)
} 1' file
```

```
"Time","pre_aggregate[0]-IN","pre_aggregate[10]-IN",
"2020-05-26 07:11:00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"2020-05-26 07:11:15",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"2020-05-26 07:11:30",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
"2020-05-26 07:11:45",290.51666666666665,290.53333333333336,
"2020-05-26 07:12:15",1027.15,1027.15,1028.85,1028.8666666666666,
"2020-05-26 07:12:30",1394.1166666666666,1394.15,1394.15,1394.1333333333334,
"2020-05-26 07:12:45",1475.5333333333333,1473.3666666666666,
```

`n=$1/1000` is done to convert milli-sec value to second value before calling `date` command to convert into `Y-m-d H:M:S` format.

Comment: and how do I add the quotes `"` in the begin and end of the date?

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` and `strftime`, replace first field by formatted time:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; }  NR>1{ $1=strftime("\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"", $1/1000) } 1'
```

> What am I missing in the sed command to have a date in this format 2020-05-07 08:09:45?

It's impossible to do it in `sed`. It is "theoretically "possible" to do arithmetic in `sed`, but the resulting script to handle very big values like `1590491490000` would be very, very, very long. `sed` can be used for simple regex *replacement*, `sed` is not able to "compute" or "convert" the values. Use other tools for such jobs.

> ```
> sed 's/^/echo "/; s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/`date -d @\1`/;
> ```

`sed` doesn't understand backticks ` as a command substitution like shell does. Backticks are taken literally in `sed`. There is a GNU extension to execute the content of replacement string by adding a flag `e` on the end of `s` command. Because division by 1000 is equal of removing 3 last digits, in GNU sed you could do:

```
sed '1!s/^\([0-9]*\)[0-9]\{3\},/date -d@\1 +\\""%Y-%m-%d %T\\"",/e'
#                                                                ^ execute the expression
#                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ get's executed
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^ effectively divides by 1000
#    ^^ execute for all except first line
```

Using `awk` with `strftime` will be magnitudes faster.

Comment: nice answer for both awk/sed... was about to suggest similar `sed` solution.. `1!` not needed though because it won't match the pattern

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following in pure `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  $1 = strftime("%D %T.000",substr($1,1,10))
  gsub("/","-",$1)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Adding one more solution which will have `"` to start and end of date column.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  $1 = strftime("\"%D %T.000\"",substr($1,1,10))
  gsub("/","-",$1)
}
1
' Input_file
```